# How do I map a file into the virtual memory manager in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, virtual-machine

I am trying to map a file into OS X's virtual memory manager. How do I do this on Mac OS X using Objective C?

Comment: I edited out the 'bad' parts of your question, we're still missing what language you're trying to do this in.

Comment: I am programming in Object C and C++.

Comment: You can use `C` along with `Objective-C`. You can use [mmap] https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: I am designing a DBMS and I would prefer to open and add my files directly into VM in order to address their contents.  If this has been adequately documented by Apple, then please direct me.  I work best with simple spoon feeding, so examples would be preferred.

Comment: I checked out MMAP - Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Use mmap. e.g.

```
FILE* f = fopen(...);

// Map the file into memory.

// Need the file size.
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
off_t fileSize = ftello(f); // get current file pointer
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
mappedSize = fileSize;

mappedAddress = mmap(0, _mappedSize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, f->_file, 0);

... use mappedAddress as a pointer to your data

// Finally free up
munmap(_mappedAddress, _mappedSize);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Use `fileno()` rather than accessing implementation details of the `FILE` structure. For that matter, it's probably preferable to use `open()`, `lseek()`, and `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mmap()` works, of course. Another option, given that you're using Cocoa, is to use `NSData` or `NSMutableData`. You can create the data object using `-initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` with `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` or `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` in the options. There are two different options because mapping a file is not necessarily safe. If the file is on a file system that may disappear spontaneously (network file system, removable drive), then having it mapped opens your app to crashes. The former option only maps if that's not likely to happen. Otherwise, it reads the data into memory. The latter option always maps, leaving it to you to cope with the potential for crashes.